# YandexMap при добавлении множества меток они ставятся не по координатам

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Добавляю на карту много меток (около 200) через objectManager
Абсолютно все метки выглядят вот так:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 108,
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            '53.579186',
            '39.450522'
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "hintContent": "Россия, Рязанская область, рабочий посёлок Милославское",
        "balloonContentHeader": "ООО «Дубасово»"
    },
}
```

изменяются только координаты и пропы.

При нажатии на некоторые метки их балун открывается вообще в другом месте, при чем балун как раз таки находится в правильном месте по координатам, а метка нет (скрины ниже):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же некоторые метки при приближении карты вообще исчезают со своего места.
Пробовал на чистую взять код из песочницы и вставить свои метки, там прям пример есть  (["Добавление множества меток"](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager/)),при чем не важно сколько меток, в примере яндекса взято 50 меток, я так же добавил 50, то же самое происходит.

В чем может быть проблема или это уже сама карта так тупит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это капец, проблема была в генерации мною айдишников через рандом -_-
Старый проект, даже не помню для чего даже так делалось, видимо на большое кол-во меток рандомные айди пересекались, при чем меток 200+, а айди от 0 до 100 выдавалось. Сейчас взял на 50 меток вручную прописал айди от 0 до 49 и все стало работать как надо...